# Query on database performance and software reliability

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, database-performance, transactional

**Suituation:**
Client is running a web based finance application, where the primary functionaities includes huge volume of financial transactions both in and out.
The processes are automated.
We run several cron job tasks at midnight to split the payments for appropriate customers.
Monthly on average we have 2000 to 3000 new customers with total of 30,000 customers currently.
Our transactional tables has almost 900000 records so far and expect drastic increase in comming months.

**Technologies:** Initially we used LAMP environment, With Codeignitor framework, Laravel elequont ORM for querying and Mysql.
Hosting: Hosted in AWS, T2 small instance, no load balancer implemented.
**This application was developed three years back.

**Problem:** 
Currenty our client faces downtime during peak hours and also their customers faces load time issues while reviewing their transaction archives and stats.
And also they fear in case if the cron job tasks fails, they could not able to handle the suituation. (vast calculations are made and amounts were inserted accross huge volume of customers).

**Our plan:**
So right now, we planned to rework on the application from scratch with performance and fault tolerance as our primary goal. And this application has to be reliable at least for another
six to eight years.

**Technologies:** Node (Sails.js), Angular 5, AWS with load balancer, AWS RDS (Mysql)

**Our approach:** From our analysis, we gained few straight forward reasons for the performance loss. Primarly, there are many stats for customers which access heavy tables. 
Most of the stats are on current month. So we plan to add log tables for such and keep only the current month data in the specific table.addMethod

So, there are going to be may such log table which will only going to have read operation.

**Queries:**

1. Is it good to split the ready only tables to separate database or can we have it within the single database.
2. How Mysql buffer cache differ from Redis / memcache, Is there any memory consumption problem occurs while more traffic flows in?
3. What is the best approach to truncate few tables at the end of evey month (As i mentioned about log file)?
4. Am I proceeding in right direction?

Comment: 1. no. 2. no idea. 3. cron job. 4. I think your problem could also be at server level, not just mysql. Consider too many concurrent connections issue - this can be resolved in a server conf file. Your problem might more correlate to server conf rather than MySQL

Comment: Set up mysql profiling using tools like Percona. You will get an idea of the queries firing during peak load. work on optimizing them; using cached results (to avoid querying same data again) and also increase server configuration a bit.

Comment: You should utilize read-replicas for your db where it is "read/accessed" heavily. But you should be aware that read-replicas are basically asynchronous replications. As you've mentioned reliability, it also includes disaster recovery & high availability perspectives, which are crucial for financial trx. Make use of what AWS offers, like Multi A/Z for your db's, load-balancing and autoscaling(as you've already mentioned), different regions for your app servers/anyfiles on S3 and routing options of customers residing in different areas. These are too broad suggestions of course!

Answer (score 0):

A million rows is a modest size, not "huge".  Since you are having performance problems, I have to believe that it stems from poor indexing and/or poor query formulation.

1. Find out what queries are having the most trouble.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) for suggestions on using mysqldumpslow -s t or pt-query-digest to locate them.
2. Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for discussion of how to improve them.  It may be as simple as adding a "composite" index.

Another possible performance bottleneck may be repeatedly summarizing old data.  If this is the case, then consider the Data Warehousing technique of [_building and maintaining Summary Tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

As for your 4 questions, I tentatively say "no" to each.

The various frameworks tend to make *small* applications easy to develop, but they start to give trouble when you scale.  Still, there are things that can be fixed without abandoning (yet) the frameworks.

AWS, etc, give you lots of reliability and *read* scaling.  But, I repeat, the likely place to look is at the slow queries, not the various ideas you presented.

As for periodic truncation, let's discuss that after seeing what the data looks like and what the business requirements are for data retention.